# mysql write lock

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking

I dont add any manual locking or any transaction anything, just manual running queries from php script, and execute below two update queries at the same time

```
update table_x set status = 'PROCESSING' where id = 123 and status = 'PENDING'

update table_x set status = 'PROCESSING' where id = 123 and status = 'PENDING'
```

And If I rely on the **updated rows count** then is it possible that both return 1?

> The requirement here is that from my web-server if two processes at
>   the same time try to process same row then I have to avoid both
>   processing it.

In a solution where I first run a select query to check if the status for the given id is PENDING and then do the processing, there is a chance of both processing it.

But I'm not sure what will happen if I do **just one update query** and rely on the rows updated count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem.  Use InnoDB.

One of those queries will take out an "exclusive" lock on the row in question.  The other query will try to take out such a lock, but be blocked until the first finishes (and `COMMIT`s).  Then it will see that there is no longer any row matching the `WHERE` clause, so it will say "0 rows matched, 0 rows updated".

Answer (score 4):

The Rick James answer is good (I vote it up). You can try the following test. 
Create table and insert some values:

```
create table table_x (
  id int unsigned not NULL,
  status varchar(100) not NULL,
  index(id)
) engine=INNODB;

insert into table_x values 
(123, 'PENDING'), (321, 'PENDING');
```

Then start two mysql sessions into two separated terminal. 
I cannot try two updates at the same time, but I can simulate it with a transaction:

```
session1 > start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

session1 > update table_x set status = 'PROCESSING' where id = 123 and status = 'PENDING';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

session1> select row_count();
+-------------+
| row_count() |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Second session:

```
session2> update table_x set status = 'PROCESSING' where id = 123 and status = 'PENDING';
```

The previous statement blocks until the first session commit:

```
session1> commit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Into the second session we will see:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (8.48 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

session2> select row_count();
+-------------+
| row_count() |
+-------------+
|           0 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0
```

You can use MyIsam storage engine (withou transaction), if you want, and obtain similar results. But I cannot see any advantage to use it.